# Locate in solution explorer reSharper shortcut

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, resharper

I am using ReSharper and love it!

However I have one problem, when i hit Shift-Alt-L ReSharper only locates the file in solution explorer if the folder it is located in is open.
If the folder is not open, ReSharper doesn't locate the file.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Actually, for ReSharper 4.5 we found a way to workaround this problem of VS, so in ReSharper 4.5 this is no longer an issue.

Answer (score 2):

It is known bug in Visual Studio - Solution Folders are not opened programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> combined with Visual Studio's "Track Item In Solution Explorer" works for me. The drawback is that the file is actually opened.

Comment: Just tried this with VS 2022 and I get "The operation could not be completed. Not implemented"